# Автоматическое заполнение поля информацией из блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

Приветствую.
Задача следующая:
Есть несколько N-ое количество одинаковых блоков примерно такого принципа строение:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="wrap-c">
    <p class="name">NAME</p>
</div>
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="tel">
    <input type="submit">
</form></div>
```

Повторюсь, строение примерное. Блоков несколько. Надо, чтобы текст из тега **P** автоматически заполнял текстовое поле формы в своём блоке. Человеку это поле видно вообще не будет (скрыто) - зашёл, а js/jquery скрипт сразу полнил поле автоматом.
Поле в форме тоже может быть другое количество, поэтому возможно лучше вешать на класс или id какой-нибудь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если просто текстовое поле

```js
$('input[type="text"]').val($('p.name').text());
```

Если формы в своём блоке

```js
$('p').each(function(){
  $(this).siblings('form').find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
});
```

Если формы в блоке одного из родителей

```js
$('p').each(function(){
  $(this).parents('.wrapper').siblings('form').find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Первый вариант не годится, ибо таком использовании в каждое поле попадает текст из всех параграфов.
А вот второй вариант уже избирательно работает, но есть проблема - уровень вложенности в блок у параграфа и формы разный, а siblings работает, только на одном уровне. Есть другой способ, например, указать класс главного блока и чтобы работа велась именно внутри этого блока, а не считалась вложенность?

Comment: Если как в вашем примере - необходимо просто добавить .parent()
Что бы было

$(this).parent().siblings('form').find('input[type="text"]')

Тогда будет искаться форма рядом с родителем параграфа

Comment: А если глубина вложенности и параграфа и формы большая и единственное общее - самый наружный блок враппер, как быть? В первом посте просто пример, реальность привести не могу (ещё не готова), но там всё явно более "древовидное"

Comment: В таком случае следует использовать .parents(selector) https://api.jquery.com/parents/

Это будет как-то

$(this).parents('.main-wrapper').siblings('form').find('input[type="text"]')

Comment: Простите, а вы уверены, что ошибки в коде с parents (selector) нет? просто данный вариант вообще никак не срабатывает.

Comment: Уверен. https://jsfiddle.net/rban0f84/ вот пример

Comment: Спасибо большое за пример, теперь понял почему у меня не работало. Всё дело в том, что у вас form был "голый" (без обёртки), а у меня форма была вложена в несколько своих обёрток. Поэтому не работало. Методом тыка удалил siblings('form') и заработало как надо, в итоге сейчас $(this).parents('.wrap-class').find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
Скажите, код корректен? Ну т.е. работать то он работает как надо вроде, но не нужно ли что-то добавить вместо удалённого параметра?

Comment: На всякий по siblings https://api.jquery.com/siblings/ 

Код конечно корректен. Ведь всё что между $(this) и .val(... - лишь способ указать на нужный нам input

Answer (score 0):

Полю назначенному на заполнение, задаем значение равное тексту соответствующего параграфа

```
$('input.name').val($('p.name').text());
```

Comment: Такой вариант подходит, только если на странице одно текстовое поле и один параграф, которые нужно задействовать. А блоков которые независимо друг от друга должны отработать по данному сценарию на странице много.